# How to Check for no input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, input

```
# Imports
import re

# Variables
contestants = []


def run(string):
    incorrectSymbols = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
    if (incorrectSymbols.search(string) == None):
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "no"


def bootUp():
    print(""">>> Hello judges!
>>> Today you will be viewing 6 contestants!
>>> To continue please enter all contestants names!""")
    contestantNames()


def contestantNames():
    for i in range(0, 6):
        while True:
            x = input(">>> Contestant number " + str(i) + " name: ")
            if run(x) == "yes":
                break
            elif run(x) == "no":
                print(">>> No symbols allowed!")
            elif x=="":            # Here is what im confused about.
                print(">>> You can't leave it blank!")
            else:
                print(">>> Error in run function.")
    contestants.append(x)
    print(contestants)


bootUp()
```

After reading up on this problem I found multiple accounts saying to do this simply use (variable)="" . However, this does not work for me, any other ideas?

My code is an attempt for a dance project where contestants all take turns and each judge scores each contestant. A tournament to be put simply. This part of the code would be the beginning where I obtain the contestant's names and i need to make sure they have no symbols or left blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Somehow it looks like your `run` is not working as you expected. Its returning 'yes' and 'no' not True and False. Ordering of your if else is wrong you need to fix that.
- just move up `if x==''` condition and it will work.

```py
# Imports
import re

# Variables
contestants = []


def run(string):
    incorrectSymbols = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
    if (incorrectSymbols.search(string) == None):
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "no"


def bootUp():
    print(""">>> Hello judges!
>>> Today you will be viewing 6 contestants!
>>> To continue please enter all contestants names!""")
    contestantNames()


def contestantNames():
    for i in range(0, 6):
        while True:
            x = input(">>> Contestant number " + str(i) + " name: ")
            if x == "":            # Here is what im confused about.
                print(">>> You can't leave it blank!")
            elif run(x) == "yes":
                break
            elif run(x) == "no":
                print(">>> No symbols allowed!")
            else:
                print(">>> Error in run function.")
    contestants.append(x)
    print(contestants)


bootUp()
```

- Another solution is to change run function like this.

```
def run(string):
    if string == "":
        return
    incorrectSymbols = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
    if (incorrectSymbols.search(string) == None):
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "no"
```

This will work with your default if else ordering.

Comment: rookie mistake x)